# How to extract childelement from parent tag in nested xml via xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to extract childelement from parent tag in nested xml via xslt
It has two tags with same name and I want to split it into two different tags.

My xml is like:

```
<div>
    <title> Additional info </title>
    <h2> heading </h2>
    <div>
    <title> click info </title>
    </div>
</div>
```

output should be:

```
<section>
    <title> Additional info </title>
    <h2> heading </h2>
</section>
<section>
    <title> click info </title>
</section>
```

my xslt code is:

```
    <xsl:template match="content/body//div">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="div">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </section>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="content/body/section/div">
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="./node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

using this I am getting output:

```
    <title> Additional info </title>
            <h2> heading </h2>
        <section>
            <title> click info </title>
        </section>
```

Comment: Can you say which version of XSLT you can use? Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 for example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the update for all element names that are direct children.

```
<div>
    <title> Additional info </title>
    <h2> heading </h2>
    <div>
    <title> click info </title>
    </div>
    <div>
        <em>Release</em>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the xsl

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name='list' select='//div'/>

<xsl:template match='/'>
    <div>
        <xsl:for-each select='$list'>
            <xsl:element name='select'>
                <xsl:copy-of select='*[not(name(.)="div")]'/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs

```
<div>
  <select>
    <title>Additional info</title>

    <h2>heading</h2>
  </select>

  <select>
    <title>click info</title>
  </select>

  <select>
    <em>Release</em>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I do not need the <span > tag.. 

My output should be :

<div>
<title> Additional info </title>
<h2>heading</h2>
</div>
<div>
<title>click info</title>
</div>

Comment: here tags are dynamic . may be it will be more than two .
so Our code should be generic

Comment: I've changed the output element from span to section.  If you don't need the <section> element as your question indicates, just include the copy-of statements and remove the xsl:element wrapper.  The solution will work with any number of <div> elements that contain a <title> element.  If you don't ne

Comment: Thanks for your response..
It works for the scenario if section is under section.
But if the code is like :
<div>

Comment: If the code is 
<div><titile>Additional info</title><h2>heading</h2><div><em>Release info <em></div>.<div><title>Operational commands</title></div> then how will code works?

Comment: output should be like this:                                                                            <section>                                                                                        <titile>Additional info</title>                                                            <h2>heading</h2></section>                                                                                               <section><em>Release info <em></section>                                                                                               <section><title>Operational commands</title><section>

Comment: what should we do if outer div having no child element other than div
like:<div><div><em>Release info <em></div><div><title>Operational commands</title></div></div>. Also, I dont want any empty tag in output i.e I need only inner div...Output would be :  <section><em>Release info <em></section> <section><title>Operational commands</title><section>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!!
its working now using the below code

```
    <xsl:for-each select='$list'>
        <xsl:element name='section'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='*[not(name(.)="div")]'/>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
```